# Object hierarchy from XML document using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

Given an XML document such as this:

```
<Root> 
    <Child1>
        <ChildOfChild1_1> 
            <FinalChild> </FinalChild>
        </ChildOfChild1_1>
        <ChildOfChild1_2> </ChildOfChild1_2>
    </Child1>
    <Child2>
        <ChildOfChild2_1> </ChildOfChild2_1>
    </Child2>
    <Child3> </Child3>
</Root>
```

I would like to return a object which has only two parameters, name and children. It would look like:

```
{
    name: "Root"
    children: [
        {
            name: "Child1"
            children: [
                {
                    name: "ChildOfChild1_1"
                    children:[
                        {
                            name: "FinalChild"
                            children: null
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "ChildOfChild1_2"
                    children: null
                }

            ]
        }, 
        {
            name: "Child2"
            children: [
                {
                    name: "ChildOfChild2_1"
                    children: null
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            name: "Child3"
            children: null
        }, 
    ]
}
```

I do not care about node attributes, only `nodeName` and if they have children. I wrote code to get the first level of children but cannot wrap my head around the recursive part to get as deep as necessary. Thanks.

Below is what I have so far:

```
//assuming block is the root node and the root will at least have 1 child
let root = {
    name = '',
    children = []
};
root.name = block.nodeName;

for(let i=0 ; i<block.children.length ; i++) {
    root.children.push(getChildren(block.children[i]));
}

function getChildren(data) {
    let child = {};
    child.name = data.nodeName;
    child.children = []; //stuck here
    
    return child;
}
```

Comment: Ir's not JSON just because it has curly brackets. What you (want to) have is an object, plain and simple. I've removed the "JSON" from the title. Related reading: https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task is much simpler than you think.

You want a function that returns a node name and the list of node children, each of them processed in the exact same way:

```
function toObject(node) {
    return {
        name: node.nodeName,
        children: [...node.children].map(toObject)
    };
}
```

That's it.

```js
const xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<Root> 
    <Child1>
        <ChildOfChild1_1> 
            <FinalChild> </FinalChild>
        </ChildOfChild1_1>
        <ChildOfChild1_2> </ChildOfChild1_2>
    </Child1>
    <Child2>
        <ChildOfChild2_1> </ChildOfChild2_1>
    </Child2>
    <Child3> </Child3>
</Root>
`, "application/xml");

function toObject(node) {
    return {
        name: node.nodeName,
        children: [...node.children].map(toObject)
    };
}

const tree = toObject(xmlDoc.documentElement);
console.log(tree);
```

If you *really* want `null` when there are no children (an empty array is much easier to handle down the line, trust me), I'm sure you can make the necessary change in `toObject` yourself.